# Is Spring Batch Suitable for this Scenario?

Tags: hibernate, spring-batch

I am currently working on a system with the following workflow:

1. Read data from a specific table containing more than a hundred thousand records.
2. Fetch associated data from other tables for each record retrieved from step (1).
3. After compiling all necessary data, modify and write this data to another specific table.
4. In the event of an error, abort all writing processes, including the data that has already been written to the table.

I attempted to utilize the chunk model of Spring Batch along with Hibernate but encountered some issues:

- Given the large volume of data, I attempted to use ScrollableResults with a custom reader. However, when the Session is managed by the Spring Framework, it closes after the first reader.
- When an error occurs, I have to manually delete all the data that has already been written because it commits automatically.

I appreciate the concept of the chunk model, but I'm uncertain if it's suitable for this scenario. I'm wondering if I should persist with Spring Batch or explore alternate development methodologies.

Comment: Chunks are committed, that is the whole point of a chunk. That way if something goes wrong you can either continue with the next chunk (and record the faulty records) or stop, fix the error and continue. That is the whole point of chunks. The Hibernate reader already uses a cursor so no need to write your own.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for your response. I realize how foolish my question was, and I have decided to stick with the tasklet model.